# Como puedo resolver este error : "no se puede escribir datos de en la conexión de transporte: net_io_connectionclosed."

Tags: c#, asp.net

entiendo que la solucion para VB.net :

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

eso fue lo que lei en otra pregunta, sin embargo en el caso de una aplicacion web asp.net en visual studio, tengo este metodo llamado EnviarMensaje el cual realiza el proceso de enviar correos de forma automatica se usando System.Net.Mail la clase SmtpClient para enviar, cual seria la solucion?

mi codigo es el siguiente:

````
public void EnviarMensaje(string p_To, string p_Cc, string p_Bcc, string p_Asunto, string p_Mensaje)
        {
            try
            {
                string l_SMTP_Pass = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pass_envio_correo"].ToString();
                string l_SMTP_Server = SeleccionarValorCampo0("AG_CONFIGURACION", "V_VALOR", "V_CONSTANTE", "SMTP_HOST");
                string l_From_Email = SeleccionarValorCampo0("AG_CONFIGURACION", "V_VALOR", "V_CONSTANTE", "DO_INTER_FROM_CORREO");

                if (p_To != null || p_Cc != null)
                {
                    if ((p_To.Equals("") && !p_Cc.Equals("")) || !p_To.Equals(""))
                    {
                        MailMessage mensajeEnviar = new MailMessage();
                        mensajeEnviar.From = new MailAddress(l_From_Email);

                        string[] l_ToArr = p_To.Split(';');
                        for (int i = 0; i < l_ToArr.Length; i++)
                        {
                            if (l_ToArr[i] != null && !l_ToArr[i].Trim().Equals(""))
                                mensajeEnviar.To.Add(l_ToArr[i].Trim());
                        }

                        if ((p_Cc != null) && (!p_Cc.Equals("")))
                        {
                            string[] l_CcArr = p_Cc.Split(';');
                            for (int j = 0; j < l_CcArr.Length; j++)
                            {
                                if (l_CcArr[j] != null && !l_CcArr[j].Trim().Equals(""))
                                    mensajeEnviar.CC.Add(l_CcArr[j].Trim());
                            }
                        }

                        if ((p_Bcc != null) && (!p_Bcc.Equals("")))
                        {
                            string[] l_BccArr = p_Bcc.Split(';');
                            for (int k = 0; k < l_BccArr.Length; k++)
                            {
                                if (l_BccArr[k] != null && !l_BccArr[k].Trim().Equals(""))
                                    mensajeEnviar.Bcc.Add(l_BccArr[k].Trim());
                            }
                        }

                        mensajeEnviar.IsBodyHtml = true;
                        mensajeEnviar.Subject = p_Asunto.Trim();
                        mensajeEnviar.Body = p_Mensaje.Trim();

                        SmtpClient l_smtp = new SmtpClient();
                        l_smtp.Send(mensajeEnviar);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                FileStream fStream = new FileStream(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PathTemp"] + "logmail.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(fStream);
                sWriter.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                sWriter.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
                sWriter.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                sWriter.Close();
            }
        }```


Si se necesita otra parte de codigo, la suministrare sin problemas.
````